# Linear mixed effect model in SPSS does not return same numbers in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, spss

I am doing linear mixed effect models in both R-studio and SPSS (doing this as I am trying learn LME in R). For some reason, I cant seem to get the numbers for the analyses to coincide. My dataset is on reaction time after sleep restriction or normal sleep.

Variable explanations:

- ReactionTime: Response variable, continuous
- SleepRestr: (0) normal sleep and (1) sleep restriction
- Time: 1 - 5, tested in total five times following day after sleep

In R-studio, the following values are returned:

```r
> anova(mixed.lmer)
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method

                        Sum Sq       Mean Sq  NumDF  DenDF F value Pr(>F)  
factor(SleepRestr)        0.0258791 0.0258791     1    36  5.6341 0.02307*
factor(Time)              0.0061055 0.0015264     4    36  0.3323 0.85439  
factor(SleepRestr * Time) 0.0105856 0.0026464     4    36  0.5761 0.68173  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Whereas in SPSS, the values are:

```
Type III Tests of Fixed Effects         
Source          Numerator df  Denominator df        F          Sig.
Intercept           1             4               75,685      <,001
SleepRestr          1           36,001            10,005       ,003
Time                4           36,001              ,817       ,523
SleepRestr * Time   4           36,001              ,576       ,682
```

The interaction effect does have the same F-value in R-studio and SPSS. However, the main effects are very different. Does anyone know what might be causing this? The estimates in post-hoc are the same in SPSS and R.

R-Syntax:

```r
mixed.lmer <- lmer(ReactionTime ~ factor (SleepRestr) + factor (Time) + 
                 factor (SleepRestr * Time) + (1|Subject_id), data = df, 
                 REML = TRUE)
```

SPSS Syntax:

```
DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet1.
MIXED ReactionTime BY SleepRestr Time
  /CRITERIA=DFMETHOD(SATTERTHWAITE) CIN(95) MXITER(100) MXSTEP(10) SCORING(1) 
    SINGULAR(0.000000000001) HCONVERGE(0.00000001, RELATIVE) LCONVERGE(0, ABSOLUTE) PCONVERGE(0, 
    ABSOLUTE)
  /FIXED=SleepRestr Time SleepRestr*Time | SSTYPE(3)
  /METHOD=REML
  /PRINT=SOLUTION
  /RANDOM=INTERCEPT | SUBJECT(Subject_id) COVTYPE(UN) SOLUTION.
```

Answer (score 2):

Type III sums mean that you are using the interaction term without a fixed term.

But this is ambiguous.

The interaction term can be defined in multiple ways (In the case that you include the main effect this difference doesn't matter. But with type III sums you exclude this interaction term).

Possibly this can explain the differences between ANOVA results in different packages.

The example below shows how in R you can switch the labels in order to get different interactions and different figures in the results table

```
set.seed(1)
u = rbinom(30,1,0.5)
v = rbinom(30,1,0.5)
s = 1-u
t = 1-v
y = 2+u+v+2*u*v+rnorm(30,0,1)

car::Anova(lm(y~u*v), type = 3)
car::Anova(lm(y~s*t), type = 3)
```

With the result

```
> car::Anova(lm(y~u*v), type = 3)
Anova Table (Type III tests)

Response: y
            Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept) 45.791  1 85.1582 1.099e-09 ***
u            1.964  1  3.6519   0.06709 .  
v            0.001  1  0.0024   0.96106    
u:v         15.854  1 29.4829 1.085e-05 ***
Residuals   13.981 26                      
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> car::Anova(lm(y~s*t), type = 3)
Anova Table (Type III tests)

Response: y
             Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept) 273.435  1 508.505 < 2.2e-16 ***
s            53.152  1  98.847 2.392e-10 ***
t            30.320  1  56.386 5.679e-08 ***
s:t          15.854  1  29.483 1.085e-05 ***
Residuals    13.981 26                      
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
```

note that the difference between $u,v$ and $s,t$ is just a switch between the zeros and ones.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on the interaction effect. I still however dont quite understand why the main effects differ from SPSS. Running post-hoc analyses in SPSS also give different p-values compared to R with emmeans. This is not to get too hung up on p-values, but it makes me wonder if  I have written the syntax for the model incorrectly?

Comment: @Besosk do you understand why the main effects differ in the example that I give? The principle might be the same for SPSS vs R. The difference can be because the intercept is chosen differently. You should check out which 'times' and 'sleeprestr' are chosen as factors in the model. This is arbitrary and SPSS and R might do this differently (my example shows how you can change this and how the result differed because of it).

Comment: @Besosk I don't know enough about SPSS to be able to debug the code and see whether it should give the same result as R (I also don't have the program on my computer). But you could try in R to relabel the factors such that a different interaction term is chosen. There are 8 possible ways (R chooses the lowest integer or first factor as the intercept and this gives you 2x4 ways to choose this intercept). Try them and see if one of them matches SPSS. (or more directly, check which factors and interactions are used in the models, and if they were different change them such that they match)