# 2x2 Repeated measures ANOVA gives DIFFERENT result in R and SPSS? (Same type of sums/data/analysis) Anyone know why?

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, spss, experiment-design

Reposting this because I fixed the formatting to see if someone can actually provide a solution for this problem. I have a study design in which I am carrying out a 2x2 repeated measures ANOVA in which participants give ratings (DV) for 2 types of stimulus (Stim = 1st IV) in 2 different conditions (Conditions = 2nd IV).

Now, using the same dataframe in SPSS and in R with ezANOVA I get the same conclusions, but different F-ratios. My design is balanced, and I use the same type of sums of squares (Type 3) in both analysis, but still get different F-ratios. Anyone know why?

Here is the code for the ezANOVA in R:

```
ezANOVA(
  data = NewData, dv = value, wid = ID, 
  within = .(VCondition, Stimulus), type =3)
```

and here is the output:

```
$ANOVA
                   Effect DFn DFd           F           p p<.05         
2              VCondition   1  81 0.006498711 0.945754134       
3                Stimulus   1  81 8.398604264 0.005435088     * 
4     VCondition:Stimulus   1  81 6.195138581 0.014578806     *
```

In contrast, with SPSS, I get different F-ratios, but the same conclusions, as seen below:
[image: SPSS OUTPUT]

Here is the syntax used for the SPSS output

```
DATASET NAME DataSet1 WINDOW=FRONT.
GLM LC_L LC_R HC_L HC_R
  /WSFACTOR=Stim 2 Polynomial Condition 2 Polynomial
  /METHOD=SSTYPE(3)
  /PLOT=PROFILE(Cue*Stim) TYPE=LINE ERRORBAR=NO MEANREFERENCE=NO YAXIS=AUTO
  /PRINT=DESCRIPTIVE ETASQ OPOWER
  /PLOT=RESIDUALS
  /CRITERIA=ALPHA(.05)
  /WSDESIGN=Stim Cue Stim*Cue.
```

**Does anyone have any idea what may be happening here? Why do I have different f-ratios when using the exact same test, exact same dataset, only difference being one is in SPSS and the other in ezANOVA in r?**

Comment: See here for the same type of question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/565517/linear-mixed-effect-model-in-spss-does-not-return-same-numbers-in-r Differences can occur if SPSS and R are not using the same intercept.

Comment: Something weird in the SPSS table is that you have three times a different residual.